# What HTML/CSS attributes and tools should I use to oddly layout a form with unintuitive tab ordering?

Tags: html, css

Part of my job is to take mock specs that are created by our customers and then design their custom web forms.  The application that I'm working with has it's own source of tools that we have developed for our application.  I've just received an interesting spec for a form with over 40 data control inputs, and they are organized into 6 specific sections of the screen.  For the sake of this question, I do not need to show the layout of each input but just the areas of which the user will tab their cursor.

The customer has requested a very specific order of where the keyboard cursor needs to tab through.  Below is a rough mock of the sections, numbered 1-6, where the cursor should flow as the user tabs through the display.

[image: Tab Ordering]

In getting the cursors to tab properly from section to section, this must be done entirely in HTML and CSS and not use a CSS framework.  I'll spare the reason but I also cannot use JavaScript to tab from one field to the next by using special event hooks to navigate to a specific field on a TAB key press.

I am free to define these sections using any available HTML and CSS.  HTML tabbing works from the top of the source code to the bottom.  I could try to create a bunch of div blocks and hard-coding their positioning, but I feel there has to be a better way.  Is there a way that I can define divs containing the related fields and using some form of positioning and spanning to make a tab order behave the way it needs too?

I'm not necessarily looking for the code for this layout, but I couldn't figure this out using CSS grid or flex boxes.  If someone has some specific HTML/CSS elements and attributes that add for specific placement that allows for some odd tab wrapping, I'd appreciate advisement.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to couple your layout with your tab sequence. Consider using the `tabindex` attribute ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex )

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#input1 {
  order: 4;
}

#input2 {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  order: 3;
}

#input3 {
  order: 5;
}

#input5 {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<p>Click into the "Input 4" and tab through. You can make your layout be whatever you want. It can be crazy. But, your tabindex keeps your cursor going along the path you create for it with sequential numbers.</p>
<form>
  <input placeholder="Input 1" type="text" id="input1" tabindex="4">
  <input placeholder="Input 2" type="text" id="input2" tabindex="3">
  <input placeholder="Input 3" type="text" id="input3" tabindex="5">
  <input placeholder="Input 4" type="text" id="input4" tabindex="1">
  <input placeholder="Input 5" type="text" id="input5" tabindex="2">
</form>
```

Comment: I need to clarify. I do not have access to the <input> elements at design time.  This is because we use Angular, and we have an internal field component that uses meta-data to determine the type of input and other specific properties.  I'd be nice if if had a tabindex property, but it doesn't.

Comment: Are you able to utilize Angular or plain JS to add tabindex?

Comment: No, I'm not.  I do have access to JS, but not at that level of element objects on the page.